# JavaScript Variable wont stop reverting back to 0

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver, easeljs

I'm currently working on a small tile matching game and have made it so that each time you complete the game the variable "bestTime" will store the amount of time you took to complete the session. The variable "bestTimeTxt" will then take the value and display it in text. After you have completed a session a link

will appear allowing you to start again. I have put the new text

```
bestTimeTxt = new Text("Best Time: " + bestTime , "30px Monospace", "#000");
        bestTimeTxt.textBaseLine = "top";
        bestTimeTxt.x = 500;
        bestTimeTxt.y = 100;
```

outside of the init() function so it shouldn't keep resetting I'm not sure what I am supposed to do as every combination i could think of isn't working.

here is my full code.

I'm also using easeljs for this game

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Recipe: Drawing a square</title>
    <script src="easel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


      var canvas;
      var stage;
      var squareSide = 70;
      var squareOutline = 5;
      var max_rgb_color_value = 255;
      var gray = Graphics.getRGB(20, 20, 20);
      var placementArray = []; 
      var tileClicked;
      var timeAllowable;
      var totalMatchesPossible;
      var matchesFound;
      var txt;
      var bestTime = 0;
      var bestTimeTxt;
      var matchesFoundText;
      var squares;
      var startingTime;

      bestTimeTxt = new Text("Best Time: " + bestTime , "30px Monospace", "#000");
        bestTimeTxt.textBaseLine = "top";
        bestTimeTxt.x = 500;
        bestTimeTxt.y = 100;

      function init() {
        var rows = 5;
        var columns = 6;
        var squarePadding = 10;

        canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');



        stage = new Stage(canvas);

        var numberOfTiles = rows*columns;

        matchesFound = 0;

        timeAllowable = 500;

        startingTime = timeAllowable;



        txt = new Text(timeAllowable, "30px Monospace", "#000");
        txt.textBaseline = "top"; // draw text relative to the top of the em box.
        txt.x = 500;
        txt.y = 0;



        stage.addChild(bestTimeTxt);

        stage.addChild(txt);


        squares = [];

        totalMatchesPossible = numberOfTiles/2;

        Ticker.init();
        Ticker.addListener(window);
        Ticker.setPaused(false);

        matchesFoundText = new Text("Pairs Found: "+matchesFound+"/"+totalMatchesPossible, "30px Monospace", "#000");
        matchesFoundText.textBaseline = "top"; // draw text relative to the top of the em box.
        matchesFoundText.x = 500;
        matchesFoundText.y = 40;



        stage.addChild(matchesFoundText);

        setPlacementArray(numberOfTiles);

        for(var i=0;i<numberOfTiles;i++){
          var placement = getRandomPlacement(placementArray);
          if (i % 2 === 0){
            var color = randomColor();
          }
          var square = drawSquare(gray);
          square.color = color; 
          square.x = (squareSide+squarePadding) * (placement % columns);
          square.y = (squareSide+squarePadding) * Math.floor(placement / columns);
          squares.push(square);
          stage.addChild(square);
          square.cache(0, 0, squareSide + squarePadding, squareSide + squarePadding);
          square.onPress = handleOnPress;
          stage.update();
        };
      }


      function drawSquare(color) {
        var shape = new Shape();
        var graphics = shape.graphics;

        graphics.setStrokeStyle(squareOutline);
        graphics.beginStroke(gray);
        graphics.beginFill(color);
        graphics.rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);

        return shape;


      }


      function randomColor(){
        var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        var color2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        var color3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        return Graphics.getRGB(color, color2, color3)
      }


      function setPlacementArray(numberOfTiles){
        for(var i = 0;i< numberOfTiles;i++){
          placementArray.push(i);
        }
      }


      function getRandomPlacement(placementArray){
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*placementArray.length);
        return placementArray.splice(randomNumber, 1)[0];
      }


      function handleOnPress(event){
        var tile = event.target;

        tile.graphics.beginFill(tile.color).rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);

        if(!!tileClicked === false || tileClicked === tile){
          tileClicked = tile;
          tileClicked.updateCache("source-overlay"); 
        }else{
          if(tileClicked.color === tile.color && tileClicked !== tile){
            tileClicked.visible = false;
            tile.visible = false;
            matchesFound++;
            matchesFoundText.text = "Pairs Found: "+matchesFound+"/"+totalMatchesPossible;
            if (matchesFound===totalMatchesPossible){
              gameOver(true);
            }
          }else{
            tileClicked.graphics.beginFill(gray).rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);
          }
          tileClicked.updateCache("source-overlay");
          tile.updateCache("source-overlay");
          tileClicked = tile;
        }
        stage.update(); 
      }


      function tick() {
        secondsLeft = Math.floor((timeAllowable-Ticker.getTime()/1000));

        txt.text = secondsLeft;

       ;

        if (secondsLeft <= 0){
          gameOver(false);
        }
        stage.update();
      }


      function gameOver(win){



        Ticker.setPaused(true);

        for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++){
          squares[i].graphics.beginFill(squares[i].color).rect(5, 5, 70, 70);
          squares[i].onPress = null;
          if (win === false){
            squares[i].uncache();
          }
        }

        var replayParagraph = document.getElementById("replay");

        replayParagraph.innerHTML = "<a href='#' onClick='history.go(0);'>Play Again?</a>";

        if (win === true){
          matchesFoundText.text = "You win!"

          if((startingTime - secondsLeft) > bestTime)
            {

                bestTime = startingTime - secondsLeft;
                bestTimeTxt.text = "Best Time: " + bestTime;
            }

        }
        else
        {
          txt.text = secondsLeft + "... Game Over";
        }
      }


      function replay(){
        init();
      }


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <header id="header">
    <p id="replay"></p>
  </header>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="960" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure about the logic in `if((startingTime - secondsLeft) > bestTime)`

Comment: Note that you only need to call `stage.update()` once when content changes - and not every time in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, inside gameover method, I see you are using history.go(0) on play again link.

Technically, history.go(0) means to refresh the page and all your variables no matter the scope are set to the initial values.

If you want to retain the best score for the session and continue, use the replay method instead of history.

Updated Code :

```
replayParagraph.innerHTML = "<a href='#' onClick='replay();'>Play Again?</a>";
```